# $stmt->bind_param() dynamically if condition query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php problem when want to bind_param dynamically when I using `SELECT`

this is my php code

```
$sql = 'SELECT ProductName, ProductId  FROM Product WHERE 1=1'
if($produkname != ''){
    $sql .= ' AND ProdukName Like ?';
}
if($produkcode != ''){
    $sql .= ' AND Produkcode Like ?';
}

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param ('ss', $produkname, $produkcode)
    $stmt->execute();

    //else code 
}
```

I cannot bind_param if one of `$produkname` or `$produkcode` value is empty

Comment: For argument's sake, you're missing a semi-colon for `$sql = 'SELECT ProductName, ProductId  FROM Product WHERE 1=1'` and for `$stmt->bind_param ('ss', $produkname, $produkcode)`

Comment: `WHERE 1=1`? You have a column named `1`?

Comment: @PHPglue That's a common idiom to return all rows.  WHERE expressions don't necessarily have to involve actual columns, they just need to be expressions that evaluate to true/false.  1=1 is always true.

Comment: @PHPglue In this case, he's using this so he can dynamically put an `AND` statement at the end. It's a common technique because SQL will basically ignore it because it's always true

Comment: It's useless, though. Just type `WHERE ProduckName LIKE ?`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind mysqli bind\_param arguments dynamically in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100046/how-to-bind-mysqli-bind-param-arguments-dynamically-in-php)

Comment: @PHPglue : i use 1=1 that because in some condition i don't use like statement to run the query..

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can construct the `WHERE` clause such that it does not need dynamic parameters. Use boolean `AND` conditions to verify that the variable values are `<> ''` in the *SQL* rather than in the PHP, and you can therefore accomplish it using four `?` (each variable bound twice) and no dynamic binding.

```
$sql = "
 SELECT ProductName, ProductId  
 FROM Product
 WHERE 1=1
  AND ((? <> '' AND ProdukName LIKE ?) OR ProdukName LIKE '%')
  AND ((? <> '' AND Produkcode LIKE ?) OR Produkcode LIKE '%')
";
// Then bind each variable *twice*
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param ('ssss', $produkname, $produkname, $produkcode, $produkcode)
    $stmt->execute();

    //else code 
}
```

How this works:

```
AND ((? <> '' AND ProdukName LIKE ?) OR ProdukName LIKE '%')
```

This creates a condition where the first `?` (supplied by a bound variable) if `<> ''` will cause the `AND ProdukName Like ?` to be also evaluated.  If the variable was empty, on the othre hand, the other side of this expression `OR ProdukName LIKE '%'` will be evaluated instead. That matches *any* `ProdukName` value so essentially the entire expression is canceled out.

Comment: thank you for the answered i will tried it when i at home... now i just go outside.. thank you very much have respond fastly

Comment: You're welcome. Please @ me if you have any questions. This should work just fine though.

Comment: @Hans Did you ever come back to this?

Comment: @Hans In what way does it fail? Does it return no rows, or extra rows?  Do you mean to use `%` wildcards in the `LIKE`?

Comment: that not get return data, i use % inside php variable name like this $produkname = '%' . $produkname . '%';

Comment: @Hans Interesting. Please edit your code above to show when you add the `%`, because if it is always present, then the `? <> ''` condition will not be met unless the variable is bound before.  In its current state, it may work to use an expression like `AND ((? <> '%%' AND ProdukName LIKE ?) OR ProdukName LIKE '%')` to match the otherwise empty variable with `%` added.

Comment: MySQLi does not have a `bind_value()` alternative to `bind_param()`, so you cannot just `trim($produkname ,'%')` inside the `bind_param()`.

Comment: I Have try another and work, i pun inside script directly like below : "SELECT ProductName, ProductId  
 FROM Product
 WHERE 1=1
  AND ProdukName LIKE ?
  AND Produkcode LIKE ?" , note : when i bind param $ProdukName = '%' . ($ProdukName == null ? '' : $ProdukName) . '%', and that work.. btw thank you for your help any way...

Comment: @Hans You're welcome. Next time, please include all the relevant code. We could have avoided much confusion if it was clear that the variables were already `%` enclosed.

Comment: @Hans You should add your own answer with your solution or accept an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You need more conditions:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ProductName, ProductId  FROM Product WHERE ';
if($produkname !== ''){
  $sql .= 'ProdukName Like ?'; $pdn = 1;
}
if($produkcode !== ''){
  if(isset($pdn))$sql .= ' && ';
  $sql .= 'Produkcode Like ?'; $pdc = 1;
}
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
  if(isset($pdn, $pdc)){
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $produkname, $produkcode);
  }
  elseif(isset($pdn)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $produkname);
  }
  elseif(isset($pdc)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $produkcode);
  }
  $stmt->execute(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also utilize `call_user_func_array` with `$stmt->bind_param` to do something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT ProductName, ProductId  FROM Product WHERE 1=1'

$types = '';
$params = array(&$types);

if($produkname != ''){
    $sql .= ' AND ProdukName Like ?';

    $types .= 's';
    $params[] = $produkname;
}

if($produkcode != ''){
    $sql .= ' AND Produkcode Like ?';

    $types .= 's';
    $params[] = $produkcode;
}

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    if (!empty($types)) {
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
    }

    $stmt->execute();

    //else code 
    }
```