# PHP/MySQLi using a string array in WHERE IN clause with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to make a dynamic WHERE clause to find posts by multiple posters. This is my code so far.

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($myArray), "?"));
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE poster IN ($in)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($myArray)), ...$myArray);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
```

The above code is working but only for the very first person in my array. How will I be able to get the posts from every person listed in the array?

Comment: Can't answer this until you give us an idea of what is in `$myArray`....

Comment: As a matter of practice, you should not use aliases.  [join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) is an alias of [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).  It may work now, but wait until they decide to deprecate aliases for some reason (it happens).

Comment: For example, $myArray is Array ( [0] => krithik [1] => alex )
$myArray just contains strings of a user's username.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind mysqli bind\_param arguments dynamically in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100046/how-to-bind-mysqli-bind-param-arguments-dynamically-in-php)

Comment: This code works. the problem is with your array and/or database.

Comment: What do you mean? How would I fix my array and/or database?

Answer (score -4):

Build up a string and append it to $query using a foreach loop

```
$where = "where poster IN ( "
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    $where = $where + "'" + $value + "'"
}
 $where = $where + " )"
```

Comment: Negative.  You don't use `+` for concatenation in PHP (that's javascript). Plus you need semi-colons.  Plus you should CAP CASE keywords such as `AS`

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of using prepared statements. Please don't recommend this.