# How do I pass all elements of an array (of unknown length) to a function as separate parameters?

Tags: php, arrays, function, mysqli

I have an array in PHP which may contain data such as this:

```
$data = array("Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Pears");
```

I then want to pass these values into the `mysqli` `bind_param` function. For this example it would look like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3]);
```

My question is how can I produce the same results as above if the length of the array is unknown? For example it may be five, ten or 15 elements long.

Comment: especially check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36071202/4233593) if you're running php>=5.6 and have access to the coveted splat operator

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks. I'll take a look at that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **PHP 5.6 or higher**:

```
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($data)), ...$data);
```

With **PHP 5.5 or lower** you might (and *I* did) expect the following to work:

```
call_user_func_array(
    array($stmt, "bind_param"),
    array_merge(array(str_repeat("s", count($data))), $data));
```

...but `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` expects its parameters to be references whereas this passes a list of values (thanks Barmar for pointing this out).

You can work around this (although it's an ugly workaround) by first creating an array of references to the original array.

```
$references_to_data = array();
foreach ($data as &$reference) { $references_to_data[] = &$reference; }
unset($reference);
call_user_func_array(
    array($stmt, "bind_param"),
    array_merge(array(str_repeat("s", count($data))), $references_to_data));
```

Comment: wow, I like your php<=5.5 answer, you need to add it to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5100046/4233593)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm not sure I understand that question. It's a bit late in the day :)

Comment: This is a duplicate question, and your answer is better than the originals, so I suggest you add it there also for future readers.

Comment: I don't think this works because `bind_param` takes reference arguments.

Comment: That's why the answer in the other question is more complicated

Comment: Interesting @Barmar, I didn't consider that. The [documentation for mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) suggests you might be right. I'll see what happens when I test it.

Comment: @Barmar is correct, this doesn't work. I've added an ugly workaround which fixes it.

Comment: There's another question with a very complete answer, why are you bothering?

Comment: This question is much more specific than the other question, the reading of which (let alone the answers there) makes my nose bleed. I didn't think it was a duplicate, but you live and learn...

Comment: @MattRaines yes - the way you've explained to do it above does seam much better than the answers in the other question. Thanks a lot!