# PHP mysqli_stmt object: Bind one parameter at a time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way to bind one parameter at a time in a mysqli_stmt object? i.e. something like,

```
// $stmt is a mysqli_stmt object.
// $bindvals is an array.

foreach ($bindvals as $item){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$item);
}
```

The above throws "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables" (as long as count($bindvals)>1).

My ultimate goal in this particular case is to create a function that won't need to be edited whenever a column is added to a table, so something that will work for an indeterminate number of columns.

Comment: This is not possible. Start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100046/how-to-bind-mysqli-bind-param-arguments-dynamically-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1 Or move to PDO.

Comment: PDO works like this, why don't you use it instead of mysqli?

Comment: PDO _might_ not be an option because we haven't used it in my office before.  Regardless, I very much appreciate the information.

For the moment, I'm going to do this statically and leave a comment saying that in the future we may want to refactor using PDO, as I don't really have time to wait for superiors to research PDO and tell me that I can or can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it with mysqli. This is possible with PDO, just like many other things that PDO can do and mysqli cannot.

If you want to achieve the same using mysqli, you must collect the arguments in an array and then pass them to `mysqli_execute()` or bind them using `bind_param()` with the help of a splat operator (`...`).