# Sending an array of parameters to bind_param

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement, pass-by-reference

I have the parameters to send to a prepared statement in an array, I am using `call_user_func_array` and using it as such `call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($types), $params_fixed))`, where `$types` contains the types and `$params_fixed` contains the parameters.

I ran it and got the error `Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in ...`, I searched for this error and an answer was to send the parameters by reference so I added an ampersand before the `$params_fixed` parameter however now I get the error `Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in ...`.

How can I resolve this issue? What am I missing here?

NOTE: Before learning I had to use `call_user_func_array`, I was using it as such `$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params_fixed)`

NOTE 2: below is the code for filling the array to send

```
    $params_fixed = array();
    $types = "";
    if($param_count > 0) {
      foreach($params as $param) {
        switch(gettype($param)) {
          case "boolean":
            $types = $types . "i";
            $params_fixed[] = $param ? 1 : 0;
            break;
          case "integer":
            $types = $types . "i";
            $params_fixed[] = &$param;
            break;
          case "double":
            $types = $types . "d";
            $params_fixed[] = &$param;
            break;
          case "string":
            $types = $types . "s";
            $params_fixed[] = &$param;
            break;
          default:
            $types = $types . "s";
            $params_fixed[] = null;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

NOTE 3: below is the code in question

```
public function query($sql, ...$params) {
  $param_num_sql = substr_count($sql, "?");
  $param_count = count($params);

  if($param_num_sql != $param_count) {
    $this->error = 'parameters don\'t match';
    return null;
  }

  $params_fixed = array();
  $types = "";
  if($param_count > 0) {
    foreach($params as $param) {
      $types = $types . "s";
      $params_fixed[] = &$param;

      // switch(gettype($param)) {
      //   case "boolean":
      //     $types = $types . "i";
      //     $params_fixed[] = $param ? 1 : 0;
      //     break;
      //   case "integer":
      //     $types = $types . "i";
      //     $params_fixed[] = $param;
      //     break;
      //   case "double":
      //     $types = $types . "d";
      //     $params_fixed[] = $param;
      //     break;
      //   case "string":
      //     $types = $types . "s";
      //     $params_fixed[] = $param;
      //     break;
      //   default:
      //     $types = $types . "s";
      //     $params_fixed[] = null;
      //     break;
      // }
    }
  }

  if($param_num_sql == 0) {
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
  } else {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    //call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($types), $params_fixed));

    //if(!$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params_fixed)) {


echo "<br/>types: $types<br/>";
echo '<br/>';
print_r($params_fixed);
echo '<br/>';


    if(!call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($types), $params_fixed))) {
      // an error occurred
    }

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $stmt->close();
  }

  if($result != null && $result->num_rows > 0)
    return $result->fetch_all();
  else
    return null;
}
```

and below is the code calling this method

`$dbcon->query($query, $fname, $mname, $lname, $dob, $mobile, $home, $email, $area, $city, $street, $bldg, $floor, $car_capacity, $status, $prefer_act, $volunteer_days, $backup_days);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100046/how-to-bind-mysqli-bind-param-arguments-dynamically-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind mysqli bind\_param arguments dynamically in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100046/how-to-bind-mysqli-bind-param-arguments-dynamically-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','mydb');

        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from blog where id=? and date=?");
            $title='1';
            $text='2016-04-07';
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),array_merge(array('ss'),array(&$title,&$text)));
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        print_r($result->fetch_array());
        echo $stmt->error;
```

ok if you have parameters coming from the array

```
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','jobspace');

        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from listings where listing_type_sid=? and user_sid=?");
            $title='6';
            $text='8';
            $arr=array($title,$text);
            foreach($arr as &$ar){
               $new[]=&$ar;
            }
        $types = implode(array_fill(0,count($arr),'s'));        
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),array_merge(array($types),$new));
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        print_r($result->fetch_array());
        echo $stmt->error;
```

Comment: When filling my `$params_fixed` array, I stored the variables by reference, and I got a record stored in my table, however all the records have the same value "10" and the dates were `0000-00-00`

Comment: I added the code that is filling my parameter variable above

Comment: print your $params_fixed and $types and see it has the correct values you expected before sending it to call_user_func_array()

Comment: If I print it with saving the variables by reference I get all of them as "10" and if I remove the ampersands I get the actual values

Comment: you can use like what i have posted you dont need to check type of values every value can be 's' so just prepare statically you dont need swith and case

Comment: But the thing is, my function does not have the parameters as single values, I have them all in an array so I have to loop over them store them in a new array using the reference, its not like I can use `array(&$title,&$text)`

Comment: post the sample

Comment: I edited the post above to include my method for querying and the code calling it

Comment: That is my current code, which is in above post, which when I add them to the new array I'm adding them by reference, and when it reaches the print_r I get value "10" on everything

Comment: I changed my approach to follow what you wrote and found this article too http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli and the issue has been fixed.